# How to change App Title in MacOS Authenticate Dialog?

Tags: macos-sierra, install4j

I'm currently working with a team to develop an application for Mac and Windows that uses Install4J to generate our installer. The installer needs to make changes to the users hosts file, and so requires elevated permissions to run. We're having an issue with the Mac Authentication Dialog when the installer starts - it shows "Install4J would like to make changes" which isn't ideal. UAC dialogs on Windows correctly show " would like to make changes" so it seems to be a Mac issue. We have a DeveloperID and certificate and the installer is codesigned.

How do we get the Mac Authentication Dialog that appears to recognise our app as the application that wants to make changes and not Install4J?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 6.1, it's not possible to change this title. It's in the issue tracker, and planned for a future version.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was hoping it was just something we were missing. I appreciate the quick answer!